# Sending location to the database directly

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a script that allows to get the position (latitude & longitude) and after that it  gets inserted in the input!

```
<script>
    function maPosition(position) {
        var x = position.coords.latitude;
        var y= position.coords.longitude;

        document.getElementById("x").value=x;
        document.getElementById("y").value=y;
    }
   
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(maPosition);
    }   
</script>
```

this is the result looks like!!

[image]

[image]

I want to, when the user allows the permission to get his position, the script automatically  send the position (x,y) to the database without putting the position in the input (because I couldn't the position without putting them in the input)!!!

this is my script in NodeJs :

```
<script>
    function ajouter() {
        var url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/reclamations";

        var data = { };

        data.location="X = "+document.getElementById("x").value;
        data.location+="Y = "+document.getElementById("y").value;

        var json = JSON.stringify(data);
        console.log(json);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
        xhr.onload = function () {
            var users = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "200") {
                alert(" added !");
            } 
            else {
                console.table(users);
            }
        }

        xhr.send(json);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: where is your nodejs script?

Comment: I updated my post, check it again!

Comment: That's a front-end script for the browser. One can tell from both the script tags and the content.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very close, I added a button to make it easier to run here.

```js
const ajouter = position => {

  const url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/reclamations";

  // data is an object
  let data = {};

  // there are two properties - x and y which represent latitude and longitude
  data.x = position.coords.latitude;
  data.y = position.coords.longitude;

  const json = JSON.stringify(data);
  console.log(json);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", url, true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
  xhr.onload = function() {
    const users = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "200") {
      alert(" added !");
    } else {
      console.table(users);
    }
  }

  xhr.send(json);
}

// this will show an error to make it easier to debug
const error = e => console.log(e);

document.getElementById("go").addEventListener("click", evt => {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(ajouter, error);
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="go">Go</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I would create a reusable `post` function, so you can use Objects that automatically convert to `FormData`. Perhaps this will help:

```js
function post(url, send, func, responseType ='json', context = null){
  const x = new XMLHttpRequest;
  if(typeof send === 'object' && send && !(send instanceof Array)){
    const c = context || x;
    x.open('POST', url); x.responseType = responseType;
    x.onload = ()=>{
      if(func)func.call(c, x.response);
    }
    x.onerror = e=>{
      if(func)func.call(c, {xhrErrorEvent:e});
    }
    let d;
    if(send instanceof FormData){
      d = send;
    }
    else{
      let s;
      d = new FormData;
      for(let k in send){
        s = send[k];
        if(typeof s === 'object' && s)s = JSON.stringify(s);
        d.append(k, s);
      }
    }
    x.send(d);
  }
  else{
    throw new Error('send argument must be an Object');
  }
  return x;
}
function ajouter(){
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position=>{
    const pos = position.coords, data = {lat:pos.latitude, lng:pos.longitude, accuracy:pos.accuracy};
    post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/reclamations', data, resp=>{
      /* should echo json_encode($objOrAssocArray); in PHP - or send a JSON string back with node - resp will be JSON then - access like resp.property */
    });
  }, error=>{
    throw new Error('error code:'+error.code+'; error message:'+error.message);
  }, {enableHighAccuracy:true});
}
```